# FirebaseError: Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options). after correct initialize order

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to solve this error with this answer, but with no success:

[How can I provide options when not being deployed to hosting via source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016589/how-can-i-provide-options-when-not-being-deployed-to-hosting-via-source)

Like in the answer, I first initializeApp and then used getAuth function, but still the same error. Do I miss something?

in my bot.js (I censored config data)

```
require('dotenv').config()

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const Commando = require('discord.js-commando')
const { MessageAttachment } = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client({intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"]})
const firebase = require('firebase/compat/app')
const database = require('firebase/compat/database')
const { getAuth } = require('firebase/auth')

// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
const {initializeApp} = require('firebase/compat/app')

const { getDatabase, onValue, ref } = require('firebase/database')
const db = getDatabase()

const { debug } = require('console')
const { get } = require('https')
const querystring = require('querystring')

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "placeholder",
    authDomain: "placeholder-placeholder.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://placeholder-default-rtdb.europe-west1.firebasedatabase.app",
    projectId: "placeholder-placeholder",
    storageBucket: "placeholder.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "placeholder",
    appId: "placeholder",
    measurementId: "placeholder"
  };

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const auth = getAuth(app)
const https = require('https')

const dbref = ref(db)

module.exports = class ImageCommand extends Commando.Command {
    constructor(client) {
        super(client, {
            name: 'image',
            group: 'misc',
            memberName: 'image',
            description: 'Sends an image',
        })
    }
}

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Our bot is ready to go!!!')
})

client.on("message", msg => {
    if(msg.content === 'keyword'){

        try{

            const infographicImageRef = ref(db, 'infographics/' + msg.content + '/keyword')
            var imageUrl = null

            onValue(infographicImageRef, (snapshot) => {
                const data = snapshot.val()
                imageUrl = data
            })

           msg.channel.send(imageUrl)
    
            console.log('here2');

        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        }

    }
    


})

client.login(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
```

Comment: The `const db = getDatabase()` should be after `initializeApp()` is called. Try moving it below `getAuth()`. Also use `firebase/app` instead of `firebase/compat/app`

Comment: @Dharmaraj thank you kindly! It work after I moved getDatabase().
as for firebase/compat/app I got some error before and a solution was to use compact. But I changed it now it seems it's working