# const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig); const auth = getAuth(app); const db = getFirestore();

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to firestore for my Flutter App but throws me errors. It throws [core/no-options] Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. See also: https://futter.dev/docs/testing/errors  . It also Won't Let the whole scaffold to load.

```
try {
        await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email!.text, password: pass!.text);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Home(),
          ),
        );
        FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('userdata')
            .doc(u_name?.text)
            .get()
            .then(
          (DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if (documentSnapshot.exists) {
              final snackBar = SnackBar(
                content: const Text('Username already been taken.'),
                backgroundColor: (Colors.black12),
                action: SnackBarAction(
                  label: 'Dismiss',
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              );
              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
            } else {
              FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('userdata')
                  .doc(u_name?.text)
                  .set(
                {
                  'f_name': f_name?.text,
                  'l_name': l_name?.text,
                  'username' : u_name?.text,
                  'email' : email?.text,
                  'pass' : pass?.text,
                },
              );
            }
          },
        );
      }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I provide options when not being deployed to hosting via source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016589/how-can-i-provide-options-when-not-being-deployed-to-hosting-via-source)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase app must be initialized before you use any other Firebase services so make sure the initializeApp() function is called first as mentioned in [How can I provide options when not being deployed to hosting via source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74016589/how-can-i-provide-options-when-not-being-deployed-to-hosting-via-source)